# Label height stays the same with boundingRectWithSize. iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Basically, I am trying to change my label's height like a typical chat bubble would. I have the following code in cellForRowIndexPath:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

expectedLabelSize = [cell.myMessageLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]} context:nil];

NSLog(@"%f",expectedLabelSize.size.height);
NSLog(@"%f",cell.myMessageLabel.frame.size.height);

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = cell.myMessageLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.size.height;
cell.myMessageLabel.frame = newFrame;

NSLog(@"%f",cell.myMessageLabel.frame.size.height);
```

With my NSLogs, it tells me that the height has been changed. However, when I run the app, the labels in my cells remain the same height. How can I make it so that it loads the correct height the first time the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
cell.myMessageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Part of code works now but I am now getting 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' as an error code

Comment: Do you see "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint" in the console? Decrease priority of that constraint might do the job.